# SQL query compare and get info based on two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Contacts and groupcontacts. I want all contacts from group x listed.

Table A
Tablename : contacts 
Fields : crmcListId     crmcId

Table B
Tablename: contactgroups
Fields : crmcgrId   crmcgrContactId     crmcgrGroupId

Field crmcgrID = crmListID
Field crmcID = crmContactID

I want all contacts from table a belonging to group x to list. 
From table contactgroups where crmcgrGroupID = x

Comment: Can you be more specific and clear?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like :

```
SELECT c.* FROM Contacts c WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT ContactID FROM groupcontacts)
```

OR with a join :

```
SELECT c.* FROM Contacts c 
INNER JOIN groupcontacts gc ON c.ID = gc.ContactID
```

You can then add a WHERE clause to select the IDs for a specific group.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not entirely clear what your tables look like, I'm going to take a shot in the dark here:

```
Select * 
From Contacts c
inner join GroupContacts gc on gc.ContactID = c.ContactID
where gc.GroupID = x
```

Just subsitiute x for the real group id